# access outer scoped local variable in anonymous class having same variable name

Tags: kotlin

A local variable is declared in a function. Function also have an anonymous class after that variable declaration. Anonymous class has one own function with a parameter having same name as the outer scoped local variable. There's no compiler error due to same names. And I am unable to refer to the outer scoped local variable from anonymous class' function as it's referring to own variable.

How to access the outer `token` variable in anonymous class?

```
fun function() : String {

    lateinit var token : String // outer

    accSvc.signUp("phone","email",object:AccountService.SignUpCallback {

        override fun onSignedUp(token: String /*inner*/) {
            //how to access outer 'token' here (assign inner 'token' to outer 'token') ??
            token /*outer*/ = token /*inner*/ //error on this line
        }

        override fun onSignUpFailed(error: String) {

        }

    })
    return token
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the compiler is giving the same name error. Changing the parameter name to t, worked.

```
fun function() : String {

    lateinit var token : String // outer

    accSvc.signUp("phone","email",object:AccountService.SignUpCallback {

        override fun onSignedUp(t: String /*inner*/) {
            //how to access outer 'token' here (assign inner 'token' to outer 'token') ??
            token /*outer*/ = t /*inner*/ //error on this line
        }

        override fun onSignUpFailed(error: String) {

        }

    })
    return token
}
```

Comment: I also had resolved the issue by renaming the variable, but I am amazed, kotlin has not given error that variable with same name is already declared, as their scopes are common. In case of java, it would have given this error and we would had to change the name of any one variable as per compiler's suggestion. Here we had to change the name of one variable after we write some incorrect instruction. Though, thanks for the answer (+1)